# drag and drop a copy of div into another div

Tags: jquery, html, css, drag-and-drop, division

I would like to copy div_1 into div_2 by click and drag. But keep the div_1 in its position even after copying into div_2. Only it works in onclick, please help me how to do it in drag and drop with the above said functionalities. Thanks in advance...!

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('.div_1').on('click',function()
    {
        $('.div_1').appendTo('.div_2');
    });
});
```

My code in [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/arunvalaven/322m68t4/12/)..!

Comment: use draggable and droppable from jquery ui

Comment: I have used it, drag and drop will work, but how it copy the div_1 into div_2 by keeping the div_1 in its position..?

Comment: use  `helper: "clone"` as one of its property in draggable. this will help you keeping the orignal one

Comment: Ok thanks.. I will do as per your helper.... I mean time can you please edit my Jsfiddle code by using clone helper...?

Answer (score 0):

the helper will give you ability to keep orignal element at same position

```
$(".div_1").draggable({
    //revert: "valid",
    //clone the element which is dragged
    helper: "clone",
    //draggable area in which it is acceptable
    containment: "container",
    // cursor pointer style
    cursor: "move",
    stop: function () {
        $(this).draggable('option', 'revert', 'invalid');

    }
});
```

and make `div_2` as droppable which will accept `div_1`

```
$(".div_2").droppable({
        drop: function (event, ui) 
              {
              alert(ui);
              }
})
```

Comment: Drag functionality works for div_1, but the div_2 not accept the div_1, is there anything need to change in css code..? Can you please help me through my Jsfiddle..?

Comment: @ArunValaven just check what you get in droppable ... `drop: function (event, ui) {
     alert(ui);
     }`

Comment: @ArunValaven is it helpful ??

Comment: Can you please check my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/arunvalaven/322m68t4/18/) updated code to help me how to keep the div_1 in its initial position after dropped into div_2..?

Answer (score 0):

To clone the div use `ui.helper.clone();` inside droppable drop function.

#### Use this code works fine:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var x;                            // To store cloned div

    $(".div_1").draggable(
    {
        helper: "clone",
        cursor: "move",
        revert: true
    });

    $(".div_2").droppable(
    {
        drop: function(event, ui) 
        {
          x = ui.helper.clone();    // Store cloned div in x
          ui.helper.remove();       // Escape from revert the original div
          x.appendTo('.div_2');     // To append the cloned div
        }
    });
});
```

To know live action use this Jsfiddle [link](https://jsfiddle.net/arunvalaven/322m68t4/21/)